# Form Submit without module

Tags: 8, forms, hooks

Is a module required to submit a form ?
I get a standard form from our designer and try to send it as follow:

```
<form action="/kontakt" class="sky-form" method="POST" name="kontakt">
  ...
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-u btn-u-lg" value="Nachricht absenden">
</form>
```

I have tried different function calls without success

```
MYTHEME_form_submit(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
contact_form(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
contact_form_submit(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
MYTHEME_contact_form_submit(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
...
```

i have to say, that i am a beginner in Drupal 8, so help is very appreciated.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to approach this.

One way is to use the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module. If this is just a simple contact form, you can get this done with [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) in five minutes.

The second way is create a custom module that implements a route, Form class and related methods. Wouldn't take an intermediate long, but a beginner should try [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) first.

You cannot simply paste form HTML into a twig file and expect it do anything. Drupal is ignorant to its existence and therefore no hooks will work, as you already saw.

https://www.drupal.org/project/webform

Comment: Kevin, thank you, i'll give it a try. The problem is, there are dependicies on some checkboxes. They should show some other fieldsets. I'll see.